# Make a select query with stored procedure from multiple independent tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table A

```
id | food_id |  price
1  |   3    |    5
2  |   7    |    9
3  |   3    |    8
```

Table B

```
id  | drink_id | price | type_id
1   |  8       |  8    |  3
2   |  6       |  9    |  3
3   |  6       |  10   |  1
```

Table C

```
id(food_id) |  Name
3           |  Banana
7           |  Strawberry
```

I have 3 tables like this. I want the result of the query written with the stored procedure to be as follows.

```
column 1    
13  (select sum(price) from tableA where food_id = 3)

column 2  
2  (Select count(*) from  tableB where drink_id = 6)

column 3
9  (Select sum(price) from  tableB where drink_id = 6 and type_id = 3)

column 4
Banana (Select Name from tableA a left join tableC c On a.id = c.id) where a.id = 1)
```

Suppose there are millions of rows of data in these tables. How to write the best stored procedure?

Comment: Select the values into variables for each query.  Then select the different variables as your SP resultset.

Comment: Can you post this suggestion?

Comment: You shouldn't use a `PROCEDURE` for selecting data, use a `VIEW` or `FUNCTION` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I have to use store procedure

Comment: Your question is too vague to offer a real answer. Why are your where predicates all hard coded? What you really need to post is table structures, sample data and desired output based on the sample data.

Comment: @sitera You can still define it as a `VIEW` or `FUNCTION` and then call that from within your `PROCEDURE` - it will make your code more maintainable and composable too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE:  Not validated as I don't have your tables, but this format should work once you put it into an SP.

```
-- put this into an SP


-- delcare varaibles, probably should change them to match results (could be decimal or int depending on what your SUM does)
DECLARE @SumPriceFood AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @CountDrink AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @SumPriceDrink AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Name AS VARCHAR(50)

-- get your data (not tested these as they are your tables)
SELECT @SumPriceFood = SUM(price) from tableA where food_id = 3

SELECT @CountDrink = COUNT(*) from tableB where drink_id = 6

SELECT @SumPriceDrink = sum(price) from tableB where drink_id = 6 and type_id = 3

SELECT @Name = Name from tableA a left join tableC c On a.id = c.id where a.id = 1

-- now just select the variable values you populated above for your results
SELECT @SumPriceDrink AS SumPriceDrink, @CountDrink AS CountDrink, @SumPriceDrink AS SumPriceDrink, @Name AS Name
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use your queries as subqueries.

For an Stored procedure it isn't enough but who knows what ypu need it for

> ```
> DECLARE @food_id INTEGER = 3;
> DECLARE @drink_id int = 6;
> DECLARE @type_id INTEGER = 3;
> DEClARE @a_id int = 1;
> SELECT
> (select sum(price)from tableA where food_id=@food_id) col1,
> (Select count(*) from  tableB where drink_id=@drink_id) col2,
> (Select sum(price) from  tableB where drink_id=@drink_id and type_id=3) col3,
> (Select Name from tableA a left join tableC c On a.id = c.id where a.id = @a_id) col4
> ```
>
> ```
> col1 | col2 | col3 | col4  
> ---: | ---: | ---: | :-----
>   13 |    2 |    9 | Banana
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE Getdata 
> @food_id AS INTEGER,@drink_id int,@type_id INTEGER ,@a_id int 
> AS 
> SELECT
> (select sum(price)from tableA where food_id=@food_id) col1,
> (Select count(*) from  tableB where drink_id=@drink_id) col2,
> (Select sum(price) from  tableB where drink_id=@drink_id and type_id=3) col3,
> (Select Name from tableA a left join tableC c On a.id = c.id where a.id = @a_id) col4
> ```

> ```
> EXEC Getdata @food_id = 3,@drink_id = 6,@type_id = 3,@a_id = 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> col1 | col2 | col3 | col4  
> ---: | ---: | ---: | :-----
>   13 |    2 |    9 | Banana
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cd585620fa39fe3130fca1edd4cc65f1)*